# Android Studio: export to zip File not working

Tags: android, android-studio

i am using "Android Studio Arctic Fox | 202.3.1 Patch 2" Android Studio Version which is latest version. when i click on Export to Zip File.. and also  process happend but Zip not make in File Manager.
Anyone know that What is problem?

[image]

Comment: can u show me the steps that u followed ??

Comment: I Added Step of image that i followed in question, Please Check

Comment: ok when u click on "Export to Zip File" some popup may appear for storing this file for particular path right ?? did u see that ??

Comment: yes, i can see process but i can not see that zip file in File Explorer.

Comment: are you trying to search this zip file in mobile phone ??

Comment: means, i give zip location in mobile storage?

Comment: no brother, show me the screen shot after you click on that "Export to zip " option